# ObjectDisposedException in ReceiveAsync of ClientWebSocket

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, websocket

I'm trying to use the `ClientWebSocket` class in Unity 2017.4.10f1 and I'm getting an `ObjectDisposedException`.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
    private async void ContinousReceiveAsync()
    {
        Debug.Log("Receiving...");

        while (State == WebSocketState.Open)
        {
            List<byte> _buffer = new List<byte>();
            WebSocketReceiveResult result = null;

            do
            {
                ArraySegment<byte> _segment = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[1024]);
                result = await _socket.ReceiveAsync(_segment, CancellationToken.None);

                switch (result.MessageType)
                {
                    case WebSocketMessageType.Text:
                        _buffer.AddRange(_segment.Array);
                        if(result.EndOfMessage)
                            TextRecieved(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(_buffer.ToArray()));
                        break;

                    case WebSocketMessageType.Binary:
                        byte[] _data = new byte[result.Count];
                        Array.Copy(_segment.Array, _data, result.Count);
                        _buffer.AddRange(_data);

                        if (result.EndOfMessage)
                            BinaryRecieved(_buffer.ToArray());
                        break;

                    case WebSocketMessageType.Close:
                        SocketCleanUp(result?.CloseStatus);

                        if (AutoReconnect)
                        {
                            Reconnect();
                        }
                        break;

                    default:
                        Debug.LogError("[Madapter.Websocket] Unknown WebSocketMessageType");
                        break;
                }
            }
            while (!result.EndOfMessage);
        }

        Debug.Log("Stopped Receiving");
    }
```

`ReceiveAsync` throws a `ObjectDisposedException` of Object System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream. This only but immediately happens when I'm trying to send something via the websocket.

Here is the `Send` function:

```
    public async Task SendTextAsync(string msg)
    {
        if(State == WebSocketState.Open)
        {
            ArraySegment<byte> buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg));
            await SendAsync(buffer, WebSocketMessageType.Text);
        }
    }

    public async Task SendBinaryAsync(byte[] data)
    {
        if (State == WebSocketState.Open)
        {
            ArraySegment<byte> buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(data);
            await SendAsync(buffer, WebSocketMessageType.Binary);
        }
    }

    private async Task SendAsync(ArraySegment<byte> buffer, WebSocketMessageType type)
    {
        await _socket.SendAsync(buffer, type, true, CancellationToken.None);
    }
```

And the error:

> ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
>   Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream'.
>   System.Net.WebConnection.Read (System.Net.HttpWebRequest request, System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 size) (at :0)
>   System.Net.WebSockets.ClientWebSocket+<>c__DisplayClass35_0.b__0 () (at :0)
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () (at <cfc149f8218b496788d8493c87de777a>:0)
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () (at <cfc149f8218b496788d8493c87de777a>:0)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () (at <cfc149f8218b496788d8493c87de777a>:0)
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <cfc149f8218b496788d8493c87de777a>:0)
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <cfc149f8218b496788d8493c87de777a>:0)
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <cfc149f8218b496788d8493c87de777a>:0)
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () (at :0)
>   Madness.Madapter.WebSocket+c__async5.MoveNext () (at Assets/MAD Tools/Madapter/WebSocket.cs:98)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () (at :0)
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.b__6_0 (System.Object state) (at :0)
>   UnityEngine.UnitySynchronizationContext+WorkRequest.Invoke () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnitySynchronizationContext.cs:92)
>   UnityEngine.UnitySynchronizationContext.Exec () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnitySynchronizationContext.cs:53)
>   UnityEngine.UnitySynchronizationContext.ExecuteTasks () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnitySynchronizationContext.cs:74)

Comment: `async void`. Don't do that. Use `async Task` if you have a method that doesn't return anything. `async void` is only meant for event handlers and fire-and-forget methods. It *can't* be awaited which means that any objects used by it will be GC'd sooner or later. When `await _socket.ReceiveAsync` returns, the socked is already disposed

Comment: Looks like that solved it, if you post it as answer i can accept it. Thank you very much :)